# How to setUndecorated(true) on a jOptionPane

Tags: java, swing

How can I setUndecorated(true) my jOptionPane?

I've tried everything, I'll leave below the link to the image of jOptionPane.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUWaR.png

Here's what i tried:

```
private void btnExitMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    Color temaDark = new Color(18, 18, 18);
    UIManager.put("control", temaDark);
    UIManager.put("OptionPane.background", temaDark);
    UIManager.put("OptionPane.messageForeground", Color.white);
    int resposta = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(new JFrame(), "Deseja realmente sair do sistema?", "Sair",
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,
            new Object[]{"Não", "Sim"}, JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
    if (resposta == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) { //Inverti a opção para facilitar, para o Netbeans focar no "Não", caso o usuario clique sem querer em sair
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: please read this question and answers: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/16320675)

Answer (score 0):

I think the one possible way is to inherit from JOptionPane and define new method like "showUndecoratedOptionDialog". This method would be identical with showOptionDialog but with one additional line dialog.setUndecorated(true) just before dialog.show().